# How i can access this php array string value

Tags: php, html

```html
array(3) {
  [20]=>
  string(43) "{"shortname":"testvqweq","fullname":"test"}"
  [21]=>
  string(51) "{"shortname":"bwqbdwqbwqeb","fullname":"qwbdwqbwq"}"
  [22]=>
  string(48) "{"shortname":"wqdwqdwqdw","fullname":"dwqwqdwq"}"
}
```

I want to access shortname, fullname from array like:
Testvqweqe test

Comment: They are JSON Strings that you will need to convert to a PHP Object using `json_decode()` look it up in the manual

Comment: Call `json_decode()` to decode it into an associative array or object.

Comment: `json_decode($array[0], true)`

Comment: `$obj  = json_decode($array[20]); echo $obj->shortname;echo $obj->fullname;` then `$obj  = json_decode($array[21]); echo $obj->shortname;echo $obj->fullname;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will clear things up for you I hope:

```
<?php

$array = [
    "20" => '{"shortname":"testvqweq","fullname":"test"}',
    "21" => '{"shortname":"bwqbdwqbwqeb","fullname":"qwbdwqbwq"}',
    "22" => '{"shortname":"wqdwqdwqdw","fullname":"dwqwqdwq"}',
];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);

foreach($array as $json){
    echo '<pre>';
    $j2a = json_decode($json,true);
    print_r($j2a['shortname']);
}

$j2a1 = json_decode($array[20],true)['fullname']; /*grab the value in the same line as the json_decode */
echo '<pre>';
echo "j2a1: ";
print_r($j2a1); /* Could have used an echo :) */
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [20] => {"shortname":"testvqweq","fullname":"test"}
    [21] => {"shortname":"bwqbdwqbwqeb","fullname":"qwbdwqbwq"}
    [22] => {"shortname":"wqdwqdwqdw","fullname":"dwqwqdwq"}
)
testvqweq
bwqbdwqbwqeb
wqdwqdwqdw
j2a1: test
```

I dumbed it down on purpose and did not use one lines to show how you turn the json in the array into an array and print the value you like from that one... and at the end I gave an example of a one liner without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple access them with a foreach

```
foreach(array as arrayIndex)
{
   $shortName = arrayIndex['shortname'];
   $fullName= arrayIndex['shortname'];
}
```

if you need to use the variables you will want to do that action within the foreach loop as well or alternatively you will want to store them outside the foreach loop.

GL.